# Entity Framework Core migrations: how to handle them properly in teams

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration

I got into an argument with a co-worker regarding EF Core migrations and how we should handle them in a team environment. The current process we use (which I designed) is to use a migration number as the migration name and request that every migration has a different number.

The goal of that rule is to make sure that all migration are applied in the order they are designed. If two devs work on different migrations at the same time in their own branch and use the same number, the last one to merge his code into master will have remove his migration and re-add it with a new number.

My co-worker argues that this add unnecessary work since most of the time migrations because to one another are fully independent: they will work on different aspects of the schema and therefore it doesn't matter in which order they are finally applied.

My answer to that is that this is an unacceptable risk: if two PRs creates incompatible migrations, it is next to impossible to fix the problem without reverting both PR and redo the work.

(I am aware that the current process isn't perfect: it is still possible to insert two migrations with the same number if the PRs that contains them are accepted independently or in the incorrect order. I don't have a good solution for that)

And am I overly cautious with this? Are there any best practices regarding this?